# BIOS not reaching post

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios, post

GT70 0NC-012US

Issue: BIOS not reaching POST.

Backstory: 
Several days ago my slave HD started to lock up the OS with any related programs running from that disk. In an attempt to fix it, I used Hiren's Boot CD and tried to have the HD ignore bad sectors. In the midst of trying this and that, my USB drive in which I was booting from, started appearing twice in the boot menu when pressing (F11?), in addition when posting it was displaying 99, B2, A2 slow enough to where I could see them instead of a rapid number display, at times appearing to hang at B2 and or A2.

Second weird symptom:
I noticed was in the BIOS in the Boot Manager, I saw two extra instances of my primary HD (SSD) for a total of 3. I gave one a higher priority, saved then the computer restarted. This is the were I'm currently at, it displays a black screen.

After pressing the Power button, I can feel the fan kick on, the only indication I have of anything to go with is the LED light on the exterior frame, lights the HDD LED for 3 seconds then cuts off.

I've tried so far:

- Resetting the ECU - Pull battery out, unplug PSU, hold power button down for 30-60 seconds, plug PSU back in, attempt to boot, power off, insert battery back in.
- Resetting the CMOS - Unplug CMOS battery wire from the motherboard, wait 3 seconds, plug in, attempt to boot, unplug CMOS battery for 30 seconds to 5 minutes.
- Remove GPU and RAM stick - Removed NVIDIA GPU, and the 12GB RAM stick, attempt to reboot.

I haven't had any issue with my stock cooling fan, and I do not have anything over clocked.

Currently I have the battery out of the laptop, and the CMOS battery unplugged from the motherboard, will attempt to see what happens after 12-18 hours.

From top to bottom - all info on BIOS label:

686
AMIBIOS
NB 1999
CP89
3170

Comment: I'm at work offshore and don't have the resources of trying anything else i can think of.

Comment: Please provide a BIOS brand and model. That helps with the POST codes.

Comment: Also try to plug off anything you don't really need (including HDDs) and boot from USB. See if that gets you past the POST process. I had a faulty HDD once, locking everything up in POST. Also: give your POST some minutes to get past timeouts.

Comment: Currently - created an ISO with proper rom, dos file and compiled into ISO. Mounted to USB as a floppy, inserted into USB 2.0 port, held ctrl-home; power on; released and pressed ctrl-home. Only difference i can tell now, is the fan is pushing out hot air, so maybe the CPU is actually doing some crunching?

Comment: I'm not getting any video feed, it seems like after it runs for awhile, it doesn't want to power off as quickly compared to if i boot it up for less than a minute, which allows a rapid power off.

Answer (score -2):

If there are multiple RAM slots, try using another slot. Also, try another stick of ram, as this sounds like a memory failure